# Space between two svg text elements

Tags: javascript, text, svg

I am currently working with SVG element of JavaScript.

Here is my scenario.

I have an svg element in which I have two text element like this

```
<svg>
  <g transform = "translate(0, 20)">
     <text style="font-size: 0.5em;" x="0" y="-4"> text </text>
     <text style="font-size: 0.5em;" x="70" y="-4"> value </text>
  </g> 
<svg>
```

It's appearing fine like this

**text  value**

I have used font-size 0.5em because I want to my text to resize when I resize my svg.(by using jquery resizable)
Its working fine, but the problem is that when I resize my svg the space between text decreases and at some point  the text becomes so big that both texts overlap with each other because of the fixed x and y attributes.

Is there a way to avoid this problem. A method by which I can keep the space between the two texts constant or the text can be relatively placed.

Answer (score 7):

Converting to a single text value would seem to meet the use case you've outlined above. If you need text relatively placed you can convert one to a tspan and then use dx and dy e.g. `<text>text <tspan dx="1em" dy="1em">value</tspan></text>`